# Independence of first and second sample moments (about zero) of normally distributed random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, moments

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent normally distributed random variables with means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma_{i}^2$ and,
\begin{align} M_1^2 &=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 = \bar{X}^2\\
M_2 &=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2
\end{align}

then under what conditions
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\dfrac{M_1^2}{M_2} \right) \stackrel{?}{=} \dfrac{\mathbb{E}\left(M_1^2\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(M_2\right)}
\end{align}

Also, lower and upper bounds (other than 0 and 1) for the expectation on the left-hand side are of interest.

EDIT: this question is clarified with input from @whuber.

P.S. This is not a homework question.

Comment: Expectations of products of independent variables are the products of the expectations, *QED.*

Comment: Yes, but are $M_1$ and $M_2$ independent? I now $M_1$ and $M_2^\ast$ are.

Comment: No, they are not.  I didn't look closely at that, because (1) you are focused on Cochran's theorem and (2) isn't it *obvious* the answer is no?  Consider the case $n=1.$

Comment: Thanks @whuber. As always, spot on.

Comment: @whuber, I modified the question to be exactly in line with my problem and realized I made an error in my original post.

Comment: That's more interesting.  Write $M_2 = M_1^2 + S^2$ where $S$ and $M_1$ are independent and go from there.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thanks. This is where we bring in Cochran's thm, which gets us independence of $M_1$ and $S^2$ implying independence of $M_1^2$ and $S^2$ leading to independence of $M_1^2$ and $\dfrac{1}{M_1^2+S^2}$.

Comment: Close: $M_1^2$ is not independent of $M_1^2+S^2.$ However, the nature of the dependency is clear.

Comment: Of course, I don't know what I was thinking. $Cov(X,X+Y) \neq 0$.
I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: You still ask two different questions.  The one about independence has a clear answer: $M_1^2$ and $M_2$ are *not* independent.  It would be better, then, to remove all references to that issue from your post if you wish to address the expectations.  If you were to ask about the *reciprocals* of those expressions, the expectations could all be found in terms of properties of [non-central F distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution).

Comment: Done, thanks for your help in finetuning the question.